# How can I get a list of four letter words using the grep command in the Linux terminal?

Tags: linux, unix, count, grep

I need to get the number of four letter words using the grep command in the Linux shell. My idea was to create a list of four letter words and then use a pipe with `| wc -l`.

I'm pretty new to Linux, but I have tried the following:

```
cat your_file | grep -c '^[ \t]*[a-zA-Z]\{5\}[ \t]*$'
```

and

```
grep -o -w "\w\{5\}" your_file
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -lne 'print for /\b([A-Za-z]{4})\b/g' in_file
```

Example:

```
echo 'ABCD abcd abcd1 abcd_ Abcd,Abcd.' | perl -lne 'print for /\b([A-Za-z]{4})\b/g'
```

Output:

```
ABCD
abcd
Abcd
Abcd
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.

`[A-Za-z]{4}` : Any 4 letter word = a letter, uppercase or lowercase, exactly 4 occurrences.
`([A-Za-z]{4})` : The above, parenthesis used to capture the 4 letter word.
`\b([A-Za-z]{4})\b` : The above, flanked by a word boundary `\b` on both sides, which makes it a separate word.
`print for /(...)/g` : iterate over the captured patterns and print all occurrences.

The regex uses this modifier:
`/g` : Multiple matches.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes): Quantifiers; Character Classes and other Special Escapes; Assertions; Capture groups](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions)
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)